# Regex for ending with a specific word

Tags: regex

I have following regex sandbox

https://regex101.com/r/5rcScT/4

When I use `\w*-[Ff]iltered\b` it gets `fff-filtered-qq` and `nope-Filtered-ok` which I do not want. I only want words specifically ends with -filtered. Such as `this-filtered` and `wow-Filtered`

What I am missing here?

Comment: `-` is not a word character.

Comment: I think he is **literally** trying to match the "-filtered" --  I think he wants the dash as a literal character as far as I can tell ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a whitespace boundary `(?!\S)`:

```
\w*-[Ff]iltered(?!\S)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5rcScT/5)

To make sure you match at least 1 word char before a hyphen, replace `*` with `+`:

```
\w+-[Ff]iltered(?!\S)
```

The `(?!\S)` is a [*negative lookahead*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) that fails the match if there is no non-whitespace char immediately to the right of the current location, i.e. it matches the location that is followed with whitespace or end of string (it is equal to the `(?=\s|$)` positive lookahead, but is more efficient due to the absence of alternation).

Comment: @dawg Looks like some mass downvoting wave, it happens every now and then.

Answer (score 1):

You can use alteration with either a whitespace character or end of line (with `/m` flag):

```
/\w*-[Ff]iltered(\s|$)/m
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/HfXZ9L/2)

This would be for a regex environment without a look around assertion (awk, ERE, etc) If you have a look around, use Wiktor Stribiżew's answer.

Comment: Not me :) this is a nice alternate as well. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. It would appear some sourpuss went and qownvoted the question and every answer. Geez!

Answer (score -2):

You can use this :

```
\w*Id\b
```

`\w*` allows word characters in front of `Id` and the `\b` ensures that `Id` is at the end of the word (`\b` is word boundary assertion).

Comment: You can see he tried `\w*-[Ff]iltered\b` in his original post ...  How is your answer any different?